# Distributing an XCFramework using both Cocoapods and Swift Package Manager

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, swift-package-manager, xcframework

In our software house, we want to create an XCFramework and distribute it using both Cocoapods and Swift Package Manager. Actually, we have two different projects: the first one uses Cocoapods for third party dependencies and the second one uses SPM for the same reason. The only difference between these projects are the dependencies of third party libraries: other than that, the code inside are exactly the same.

We want to understand if there's a way to create a unique project (that uses, for instance, Cocoapods), generate an XCFramework and distribute it using both Cocoapods and SPM without having issues and/or troubles derivated by the dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, many frameworks do that exactly (for example [Bugsee](https://docs.bugsee.com/sdk/ios/installation/)). For instructions see:

https://github.com/bielikb/xcframeworks#Distribution-of-xcframeworks

Comment: Bugsee does't use external dependencies, therefore they don't have our troubles. Our main problem is this: we have a project that uses, for instance, Alamofire as third party depencency and we use Cocoapods. Than, we create the XCFramework and we can distribute it through Cocoapods without any troubles even if Who implements that XCF already uses Alamofire. The problem arises when we distribute the same XCF with SPM and who implements our XCF already uses Alamofire with SPM or Cocoapods.

Comment: Try adding `dependencies: [ .package(url: "https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git", from: "5.0.0") ]` to your Package.swift.

Comment: Bugsee does not use xcframeworks though, which is the question.